# Multiplication Symbol not properly displaying in ggplot2 axis label when using an expression

Tags: r, ggplot2

When constructing an axis title in `ggplot` I want to have AUC_inf hr*(ug/ml).

I used:

```
ylab <- bquote(AUC[inf]~(hr*(μg/ml)))
```

This allowed me to subscript inf, but does not allow me to use the multiplication symbol as it is a reserved character.

Comment: Use `%*%` ... see `?plotmath`

Comment: In addition to using `%*%` as suggested above, if you genuinely want an asterisk, you can wrap it inside a call to `paste()` e.g. `ylab(bquote(paste(AUC[inf], "~(hr*(μg/ml)")))`